# Is the payment method for Lynda.com a subscription model?

Tags: lynda.com

I was talking to a friend about taking a class on Lynda.com, and they told me that I could get a free trial of the site.  I thought it worked that you bought a class individually, but it doesn't sound that way...is this the case?

Comment: This looks to be a commercial question rather than one about how to use a wep app. I think that you should contact the sales people of Lynda.com.

Comment: Did you at least go to lynda.com and look?

Comment: Yes.  They have two plans and one is standard and the other is Premium.

Comment: So then what's your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right there on the [signup page](https://www.lynda.com/signup), where you can choose either "Standard" or "Premium" and get a 10-day free trial, it also says:

> **What happens after the free trial period?**
>
> You'll automatically be charged your plan's rate on the 19th of every month unless you decide to cancel your account.

So, yes, it's a subscription model.

Also, from the [FAQ page](http://www.lynda.com/support/faq.aspx?category=185&faq=3954):

> **As a Lynda.com member, do I have access to everything?**
>
> Yes. Lynda.com members can watch each and every course in the library. Exercise files are available to monthly premium or annual premium members.

So, no, you can't purchase individual classes.

Fortunately, you may be affiliated with an organization that already has a subscription. For instance, my local public library has a subscription and I can view Lynda.com videos with just my library card.

Comment: Now that's an answer!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Lynda.com is subscription based with free 10 day trial but be careful because it asks for your credit card info (at least 2 years ago it did) even for the "free trial".